# Update listview after adding new data into database in Android

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, chat

I want to make chat room Android App, am using JSON as webservices using PHP, MYSQL & parsing it in my android app. Initially am able to see the data, but am not able to update the data in my app even after updating in my DB, I have to re-run the app to get the updated data. How do i resolve this.

code:

```
package com.example.androidhive;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Timer;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

//import com.mekya.R;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AllProductsActivity extends ListActivity {

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // Creating JSON Parser object
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> all_chat;

    // url to get all products list
    private static String url_all_products = "http://url.com/chat-app/";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_CHAT = "chat";
    private static final String TAG_FROM = "from_u";
    private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";
    private static final String TAG_DATE = "date";


    // products JSONArray
    JSONArray chat = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.all_products);

        // Hashmap for ListView
        all_chat = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        // Loading products in Background Thread
        new LoadAllProducts().execute();  


    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
     * */
    class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AllProductsActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading products. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * getting All products from url
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);

            // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
            Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());

            try {
                    // products found
                    // Getting Array of Products
                    chat = json.getJSONArray(TAG_CHAT);

                    // looping through All Products
                    for (int i = 0; i < chat.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = chat.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Storing each json item in variable
                        String date = c.getString(TAG_DATE);
                        String from = c.getString(TAG_FROM);
                        String message = c.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);

                        // creating new HashMap
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        map.put(TAG_DATE, date);
                        map.put(TAG_FROM, from);
                        map.put(TAG_MESSAGE, message);

                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        all_chat.add(map);
                    }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
            pDialog.dismiss();
            // updating UI from Background Thread

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                public void run() {
                    /**
                     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                     * */
                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                            AllProductsActivity.this, all_chat, R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_FROM,TAG_DATE, TAG_MESSAGE },
                            new int[] { R.id.from,R.id.date, R.id.message });
                    // updating listview
                    setListAdapter(adapter);
                }
            });

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: add here java code of your adapter

Comment: Mr sajmon_d, i don't undrestand what is ur mean ... :( i have not java code adapter , what gon id do ?

Comment: Mr sajmon , I use defult listadapter. i used "import android.widget.ListAdapter;"

Answer (score 0):

The process should be something like this,

Assume that this is your url: `http://www.xxx.com/get_chat.php?id=""`
Server should send response based in id parameter. If it has nothing send whole list otherwise sends new data newer than that id.

So, first time you will get the whole list and after that server just sends new data, based on what is the id of last item. Based on what you have mentioned I assume that you can update your database.

Now assume that you have a timer and your application is sending request to server every one second (This is horrible assumption if you want to make it real. just assume that 10000 devices are sending request to server every one second!). 
**If there is no data**: don't do any thing (it should be checked on onPostExecute method)
**If there is data**: get the whole list from database (since new data has been added before and therefore, you will have updated items) and pass it to your adapter.

Hope it helps you :)